# NOT NULL constraint failed: app_business.user_id

Tags: python, django

I am rendering a form and when I am submitting that form getting this error

> IntegrityError at /business/
>   NOT NULL constraint failed: app_business.user_id

models.py

```
class business(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    rate_it = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    availibility = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class businessform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = business
        fields = ['name', 'rate_it', 'availibility']
```

views.py

```
def formview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = businessform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('saved')
    else:
        form = businessform
        return render(request, 'business.html', {'form':form})
```

html file

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

 {{form.as_p}}

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I don't know why this error is coming.

Comment: show your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saving the `form` you haven't passed any `user` object. Either pass `user` object while saving the `form` or make the `user` field `null=True, blank=True` in your model.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

**EDIT**

Create an `user` object and save it first. Then pass that instance in the form to update values you got from template. Then save the form.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
user.save()
obj = business.objects.create(user=user, name="")
form = form = businessform(request.POST, instance=obj)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

**Be careful about the usernames. Usernames must be unique. So, you need to generate those.**

Comment: can you tell me how to pass that in form ?

Comment: @MandeepThakur wait. updating my answer.

Comment: could you please take a look at this question. I want to implement this       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512409/get-details-of-users-those-who-rate-the-business

Comment: @MandeepThakur Ok. Checking.